# Python's keyboard library need super user on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: python, keyboard, permissionerror

recently I have made a CLI program using Python and it uses a library called `keyboard`. The program is working very well but have something that hurts me...

For any reason when I start it in Windows works normally, but on Linux (probably on MacOS too) gives a error of permission. What i know about this library is that it captures the keys even when the terminal windows is inactive, maybe the Linux think this dangerous and ask for super user. I particularly don't care to get the user "keypressers" even when the terminal window is inactive (Only in active terminal is great for me)

then I looked for some libraries similar this one, but for any reason don't work pretty similar. the `keyboard` library has a function called `is_pressed()` that returns a boolean value based if a specific key is pressed, for example: `if is_pressed('space')`, but I didn't find a alternative library that have a similar function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is for a game, you might want to take a look at the `pygame` framework. It has an eventloop specifically for this kind of purpose. Docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html).

Comment: Well, I will take a look if this one will work thank you anyway

Comment: Update: Nope, I need to run a graphical interface to key events work. (And my program isn't a game), It's sad.